# attempt to perform arithmetic (add) on string and number Error

Tags: lua, roblox

**when I touch the object, I want it to be deleted and come back after 2 seconds and add 1 coin. how can I do this?**

```
local WheatAmount = script.Parent
local oyuncuParasi = "Coins"
duvar = false

function onTouch(vurus)
    if duvar == false then
        oyuncuParasi = oyuncuParasi +1;
        duvar = true
        vurus.Parent:Destroy()
        WheatAmount.CanCollide = false
        wait(2)
        WheatAmount.CanCollide = true
        duvar = false
    end
end

        script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouch)
```

Comment: Have you set up [your leaderstats](https://create.roblox.com/docs/building-and-visuals/ui/leaderboard-system) to have a `Coins` value?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add 1 to `local oyuncuParasi = "Coins"` which is currently a string...

Try this:

```lua
local WheatAmount = script.Parent
local oyuncuParasi = 0
duvar = false

function onTouch(vurus)
    if duvar == false then
        oyuncuParasi += 1; -- Adds a coin
        duvar = true
        WheatAmount.Transparent = 1 -- Set the object Transparent 
        WheatAmount.CanCollide = false
        WheatAmount.CanTouch = false
        wait(2)
        WheatAmount.Transparent = 0 -- Set the object Not Transparent
        WheatAmount.CanCollide = true
        WheatAmount.CanTouch = true
        duvar = false
    end
end

        script.Parent.Touched:connect(onTouch)
```

Note: Make sure you put this in a server sided script instead of local script in the Object.

Let me know if it worked and the results!!